# Ocultar de input date el año d-m-Y a d-m

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando con un input date y por un caso muy especifico me pidieron que solo muestre el dia y el mes para dejar espacio para un icono svg

[image: Imagen ejemplo]

Algo como lo mostrado en la imagen, el caso es que aunque intente cubrirlo ajustando el tamaño de la fuente mediante CSS de la siguiente manera:

```
.suba.second {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.3vw 0.1vw;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.second input[type="date"]{
    padding: 1vw 0;
    font-size: .94vw;
    height: 1vw;
}

.second input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -0.7vw;
    width:5vw;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.suba.second svg{
    margin-left: 3.5vw;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1vw;
    margin-left: 1.7vw;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Y en HTML

```
<div class="suba second">
                                            
 <input type="date">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16.297" height="16.297" viewBox="0 0 16.297 16.297">
   <path id="Icon_awesome-chevron-circle-down" data-name="Icon awesome-chevron-circle-down" d="M16.86,8.711A8.149,8.149,0,1,1,8.711.563,8.147,8.147,0,0,1,16.86,8.711ZM9.27,12.454,13.722,8a.785.785,0,0,0,0-1.114l-.559-.559a.785.785,0,0,0-1.114,0L8.711,9.667,5.373,6.329a.785.785,0,0,0-1.114,0L3.7,6.888A.785.785,0,0,0,3.7,8l4.452,4.452A.789.789,0,0,0,9.27,12.454Z" transform="translate(-0.563 16.86) rotate(-90)" fill="#cacdd5"/>
  </svg>                                            
</div>
```

Pero no logra cubrir exitosamente el año, por lo que me pregunto si se podria evitar mostrar en el display quedando en formato mostrado solo "dd/mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues ya encontre una posible solucion y fue mediante JQuery siendo esta la siguiente

```
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker( {
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
   jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
  }
 });
});
```

Y en HTML

```
<input name="findate_0_0" id="findate_0_0" class="date-picker" />
```